# ASP.NET MVC Combo Box Value Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is regarding the combo box values handling problem. Now In the Create action, I'm getting the value list and assigning it to temp data. Then I'm mapping those data to fill in the create view, to the combo box. So then I submit the data it goes to the database and save it.
Then I go for the edit view. It shows only the Id value. Even I loaded temp data is loaded but not according to the value.

This is my code of how I getting data and assigning to the temp data

```
List<M_Department> DepList= db.Department.Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList();
List<SelectListItem> DepDropdown= DepList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.DepName, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

TempData["DepList"] = DepDropdown;
```

This is how I calling those TemData to the view.

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> Departments= (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("DepList");
}

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                   Department
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Dep_Id, Departments, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dep_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Edit view, its shows the value. I want to load data and select that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Dep_Id, new SelectList(Model.DepList, "Id", "DepName", "Please Select Department"), new {@class = "js-dropdown" })
```